# JavaScript Cookie - Form not passing the utm_source value

Tags: javascript

I'm using the JavaScript to create a cookie that will post the utm_source value="".

On the console I see the utm_source value, but not on the form

```
    // Parse the URL
    function getParameterByName(name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
            results = regex.exec(location.search);
        return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    // Give the URL parameters variable names
    var source = getParameterByName('utm_source');

    // Set the cookies
    if(Cookies.set('utm_source') == null || Cookies.set('utm_source') == "") {
        Cookies.set('utm_source', source);
    }

    // Grab the cookie value and set the form field values
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[name=utm_source').val(utm_source);
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Where does your `Cookies` variable come from? If you're using a library, please provide a link to it. Also, on this line: `$('input[name=utm_source').val(utm_source);`, you're missing a closing bracket, and you're using a `utm_source` variable which is not defined anywhere in the snippet you posted. Did you mean `source` instead? Finally, in your last block "Grab the cookie value and set...", you're not actually using cookies at all.

Comment: Im suing the following from jQuery.

https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem 1**

```
$('input[name=utm_source').val(utm_source);
```

The above line is causing problems for two reasons:

- You're missing a closing bracket
- `utm_source` is not defined anywhere *(in the snippet you posted)*

If you want to use the cookie value, you should do this:

```
$('input[name=utm_source]').val(Cookies.get('utm_source'));
```

---

**Problem 2**

On this line:

```
if(Cookies.set('utm_source') == null || Cookies.set('utm_source') == "") {
```

I think that you're mistakenly using `.set()` instead of `.get()` and that it could be simplified into this:

```
if(!Cookies.get('utm_source')) {
```

which would work because `null` and `""` are both falsy values.

Comment: I used your recommended source code, but it didn't work.

Comment: <input  id="utm_source" name="utm_source" value="" type="hidden" />

Comment: I see the value="" on the console but not in the source code. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Where do you see `value=""`? If you're looking in the "Elements" panel of Chrome, you won't see it, it's normal. You have to use your console. Try typing this in your console: `$('input[name=utm_source]').val()` What do you get?

Comment: I was expecting to see the value="" when viewing the source code.

Comment: Im able to see the cookie value on the console > application > cookies

Comment: `value=""` as you see it in the HTML code is an HTML attribute. It generally defines the initial state of your element. When you're setting the value as you do with jQuery, you're not changing this attribute, but a property of the DOM element (_Document Object Model_ - a virtual representation of your HTML). That's why you don't see it and it's fine. But if you really want to see it in the "Elements" panel, you could do this instead of what you already have: `$('input[name=utm_source]').attr("value", Cookies.get('utm_source'));`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys! Got it to work! Had to replace the name=customID